# Is there a pandas function to filter a DataFrame by multiple value comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a two `pd DataFrames`, and I would like to filter one by checking if values of several columns exist in the same row in the other `dataFrame`.

Example DataFrame1:

```
   CHROM POS  ALT  Col4
r1   X    22   A    4
r2   1    43   T    6
r3   3   100   C    7
r4  15    22   A    13
```

DataFrame 2:

```
   ALT   chrom   Col3  Col4  start
r1  A      X      25    26    22
r2  A      1      18    19    26
r3  C      3      99    10   100
r4  T      1     100    88    43
```

I want to filter `dataframe 2` by matching the ALT chrome and start columns to the Alt CHROM and POS columns in `dataframe one`. I only want to keep rows that match all 3 columns.

So far I've done this with a for loop but it's quite slow. Is there a way to do this with a pandas function?

```
p = []
for x in dataframe1.index:
  for y in dataframe2.index:
    if (dataframe2.chrom[y] == str(dataframe1.CHROM[x])) and (datafrmae2.start[y] == dataframe1.POS[x]) and (dataframe2.Alt[y] == dataframe1.ALT[x]): 
      p.append(y)

dataframe2_filt = dataframe2[dataframe2.index.isin(p)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join both dataframes and keep the rows that have a match in `dataframe_1`:

```
dataframe2_joined = pd.merge(dataframe_2, 
                             dataframe_1, 
                             left_on=['ALT', 'chrom', 'start'],
                             right_on=['ALT', 'Chrom', 'POS'],
                             how='left')
dataframe2_filt = dataframe2_merged[dataframe2_merged.POS.notnull()]
```

Comment: Why not use `how='inner', the default value?

Comment: Yes, more concise, I just felt like using two steps was easier to grasp.

Comment: I tried using this method, however it did not filter the data frame. All I see is that the data_frame_1 columns are now in data_frame_2 however all of the values are set to NAN. When I run the second strip, I end up with an empty dataframe.  I tried using the "how = inner" option but that also gave me an empty dataframe. Perhaps I should specify that the dataframes don't have similar dimensions. Not sure if this would impact the function or not.